# "type" Command Not Working As Expected on Git Bash

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, git-bash

The `type` command, in Linux, returns the location, on the filesystem, of the given file, if it is in the current folder or the `$PATH`. This functionality is also available on Windows with the `Git Bash` command line program. However, I have run into what seems like a strange corner case where the file exists on the `$PATH` but doesn't get returned using the command.

I am thinking of buying a new computer soon, so I looked up the method of transferring the license key from one computer to another, in preparation for actually doing this. [The method I found](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-do-you-transfer-windows-8-licence-to-a-new/1424b725-4aa2-4c93-a559-1b35542d72a7) mentioned the files `slmgr.vbs` and `slui.exe`, both of which reside in the `C:/Windows\System32` folder, which is in my `$PATH`, as usual for a Windows computer. However, these two files aren't showing up when I use the `type` command. Also, `slmgr.vbs` gets executed when I call it in `Git Bash`, but not `slui.exe`. (`slmgr.vbs` can't execute *correctly* with `Git Bash`, but I can call it with the `cmd` CLI from `Git Bash`.) Finally, `slmgr.vbs` is shown when listing the folder's contents in `Git Bash`, as well, but `slui.exe` isn't.

I thought this might have to do with permissions, and, indeed, both files have very restrictive permissions, as you can see in the pictures below, but they both have the same permissions, which wouldn't explain why one gets executed and the other doesn't when called directly, nor why one file is listed on command line but the other isn't.

`C:\Windows\System32` folder, proving the files exist:

[image]

File permissions for the `Users` and `Administrators` groups for the two files (they are identical):

[image]

And the folder:

[image]

`type` command and its output in `Git Bash` for the 2 files, plus listing the files in the folder (using `grep` to filter as the folder is huge), as well as listing part of the `$PATH` (keep in mind, while reading, that `Git Bash` changes the paths as they are displayed):

```
Sean@MYPC ~
$ type -a slmgr.vbs
sh.exe": type: slmgr.vbs: not found

Sean@MYPC ~
$ type -a slui.exe
sh.exe": type: slui.exe: not found

Sean@MYPC ~
$ slmgr.vbs
/c/WINDOWS/system32/slmgr.vbs: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/WINDOWS/system32/slmgr.vbs: line 2: `' Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. A
ll rights reserved.'

Sean@MYPC ~
$ slui.exe
sh.exe": slui.exe: command not found

Sean@MYPC ~
$ ls /c/Windows/System32/slui.exe /c/Windows/System32/slmgr.vbs
ls: /c/Windows/System32/slui.exe: No such file or directory
/c/Windows/System32/slmgr.vbs

Sean@MYPC ~
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Sean/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/cmd:/c/Python33/:/c/Program
Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/WINDOWS/sy
stem32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell
/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Progr
am Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/
Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Int
el(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/c/Progr
am Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/c/strawberry/c/bin:/c/strawberry/pe
rl/site/bin:/c/strawberry/perl/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.
NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Pro
gram Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/90/Tools/binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Open
AFS/Common:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Wind
ows Performance Toolkit/:/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd
:/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installe
r/:/c/Ruby200-x64/bin:/c/Users/Sean/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit/:/c/Program Files
 (x86)/SSH Communications Security/SSH Secure Shell:/c/Users/Sean/Documents/Lisp
:/c/Program Files/GCL-2.6.1/lib/gcl-2.6.1/unixport:/c/Chocolatey/bin:/c/Users/Se
an/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin:/c/Program Files/Oracle
/VirtualBox:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:/c/Program Files/Node-Growl:/c
/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files/eclipse:/c/MongoDB/bin:/c/Program Files/7-Zip:/
c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application:/c/Program Files (x86)/LibreOffi
ce 4/program:/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenOffice 4/program
```

What's happening? Why aren't these files listed with the `type` command? Is this issue because of weird Windows permissions, or something even weirder? If permissions, why do they seem to have the same permissions, yet both are not handled in the same way?

**EDIT** I tried @RossRidge's answer, putting the invisible, virtual `C:\Windows\Sysnative` folder in my `$PATH`. My results are below:

```
Sean@MYPC ~
$ type -a slmgr.vbs
sh.exe": type: slmgr.vbs: not found

Sean@MYPC ~
$ type -a slui.exe
slui.exe is /c/WINDOWS/Sysnative/slui.exe

Sean@MYPC ~
$ slmgr.vbs
/c/WINDOWS/system32/slmgr.vbs: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/WINDOWS/system32/slmgr.vbs: line 2: `' Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. A
ll rights reserved.'

Sean@MYPC ~
$ slui.exe

Sean@MYPC ~
$ ls /c/Windows | grep sysnative

Sean@MYPC ~
$ ls /c/Windows/sysnative | grep pla
AutoWorkplace.exe*
AutoWorkplace.exe.config
AutoWorkplaceN.dll*
DeviceDisplayStatusManager.dll*
Display.dll*
DisplaySwitch.exe*
```

As you can see, the `Sysnative` is not listed when listing the contents of the `/c/Windows` (again, filtering for brevity), but listing the contents of `/c/Windows/Sysnative` works. Executing both `slmgr.vbs` and `slui.exe` without specifying a path to them also works (`slmgr` still needs arguments I'm intentionally not giving it). The really strange part, however, is that the `type` command now lists `slui.exe` as being in the `/c/Windows/Sysnative` folder, but `slmgr.vbs` is still not shown. Why am I able to execute it, yet it still does not show up with the `type` command?

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of your git bash session, you should cut & paste it into your message as text. You can also demonstrate the existence of the two commands with `ls -l /c/windows/system32/slmgr.vbs /c/windows/system32/slui.exe` in this session and remove the Explorer screenshot. Since your user name apparently is "Sean" and not "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" the screenshots of the permission dialogs aren't very enlightening and can also be removed. The `ls -l` command is also more informative as it shows the permissions as bash sees them.

Comment: I had the folder screenshot to prove that the files were there, as `Git Bash` apparently wasn't seeing both of them I will change the post according to your other points, though.

Comment: Looking at the permissions again, it appears the folder has `read`, `read & execute`, and `list folder contents` permissions for the `Users` group, but only `Special permissions` for the `Administrators` group. Even not counting the inane permissions names, this just seems bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've run into the WOW64 redirector. The file you want is in `c:\windows\system32` but as the shell and other utilities are 32-bit programs they get redirected to `c:\windows\syswow64`. The simple solution to your problem is to run the command you want from the normal (64-bit) Windows command line.

If you really want to run these commands from the MSYS environment you can either run the command `/c/windows/sysnative/slui` or add `/c/windows/sysnative` to your path. You may need to use the `cscript` command to run the VBScript file.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I noticed `sysnative` is not actually in the `/c/windows` folder, as a file or folder, why is that? Also, I can run `slmgr` if I switch to the Windows command line in `Git Bash` by typing `cmd`, so I don't need `cscript`, but thanks.

Comment: Also also, should I put `/c/Windows/Sysnative` before or after `/c/Windows` and/or `/c/Windows/System32`?

Comment: After - I'm not absolutely certain that putting it before would break anything, but it would be dangerous.  You can't see sysnative in the windows folder because it isn't real, it it handled by the redirector.

Comment: Strange - now I can execute both from `Git Bash`, but `type slmgr.vbs` still shows nothing, while `type slui.exe` shows this file in the `/c/WINDOWS/Sysnative` folder. I wonder if this is related to `slmgr.vbs` already executing even when I didn't have the `Sysnative` folder in my `$PATH`?

Comment: I accepted this answer (finally), but I'd still like to know about why the VBScript file is still not showing up with the `type` command.

Comment: Probably because of an inconsistency in the MSYS bash. Perhaps when it searches for it when you use `type -a` it see that's it's an executable because of the `.vbs` extension, but because of the extension it knows it can't actually run it. When you do try to run it, it treats like it would on Unix/Linux, ignoring the extension and running it as a bash script because it's has the executable permission bit set but fails to run when pass to one of the `exec` functions. Ultimately I don't see how this matters much to you, as either way bash isn't able to run the VBScript file correctly.