# type .git\HEAD doesn't work in Git Bash of Windows 10

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I want to use this command `type .git\HEAD` in the Git Bash of Windows 10, but I just got this:-

```
bash: type: .gitHEAD: not found
```

But the head file really exists under the folder `.git`. I tried `type .git/HEAD` and `type .git\\HEAD` as well, with no luck.

How can I got that fixed?

Comment: For a bit more edification, run `type type` in your bash session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a bash session, try instead:

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

That should return something like:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

`cat` is the analogous *Unix* command of [`type`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPE_(DOS_command)), which originated as an internal command in [86-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86-DOS).
The default path in a git bash session does not include system32 commands, as described in "[`type` command not working as expected on Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436822/6309)"